# Apply class on a table of GridView Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I want to apply class on table generated by `GridView::widget()` in Yii2.

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'mobile_number',
            'email:email',
            'name',
            'national_id',// and so....
```

How can I apply the CSS on the table `GridView::widget()`? I want to apply this:

```
<table class="table tblSec">
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`tableOptions`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$tableOptions-detail) property for this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table tblSec'],
    // ...
]) ?>
```

Comment: and how can I add an ID?

Comment: @ValRob i believe `'tableOptions' => ['id' => 'table_new_id'],`